# Hide-selected in multiple components sharing the same items prop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, v-select

So I basically have multiple `v-select` that all share the same `:items` prop. Now if an item is selected from one of the `v-select`, I want to hide it from all `v-select` so we can't choose it again. Inverse logic when the item is free again.

Is that possible?

```html
<div v-for="(filter, index) in group.filterMeta" :key="index">
    <v-select
      v-model="filter.tag"
      :items="availableTags"
      :label="i18n('select.tag.label')"
    >
    </v-select>
</div>
```

```js
@Component
export default class ManageGroupDialog extends Vue {
    ...
    /** Available tags */
    public availableTags = ['resource', 'resource_type', 'host', 'technology']
    ...
    public group: Group = {
        ...
        filterMeta: [
            {
                 tag: '',
                 value: '',
                 operator: ''
            }
        ]
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use a commuted property for the v-select options list, if the selected item (as a data attribute) is selected, it is then removed from that computed property. 

If you can show some code examples, then I can help show you how to implement it.

Comment: You mean computed property?

Comment: Added code example @Alicia

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with multiple components looks like you need to start using `Vuex`. This way you can have a global state, and use the same items array in all your `v-selects` over your components.